# Reverse DeleteDuplicates using Information from Tally

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of values, e.g., `{1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5}`. I delete the duplicates with

```
DeleteDuplicates[{1, 1, 1 ,2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5}];
```

> `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`

I want to perform some calculations on each value and at the end reverse the process of deleting.

From `Tally` I know, how often the elements appear:

```
Tally[{1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5}];
```

> `{{1, 3}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}, {4, 5}, {5, 1}}`

Now, from the calculations I have the new list `{12, 14, 15, 16, 17}`. I want to reverse the process of `DeleteDuplicates` on this list. Means: `{{12,3},{14,2},{15,2},{16,5},{17,1}}` -> So, that I get:

> `{12, 12, 12, 14, 14, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17}`.

I want to do that, because the calculations take very long and I want to calculate duplicates two times.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of memoization in *Mathematica*? It would allow you to map a function over the original list but only perform the long calculation once for each unique value.

Comment: Are the starting list and the second list always sorted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
tal = {{1, 3}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}, {4, 5}, {5, 1}};

lis = {12, 14, 15, 16, 17};

Flatten @ MapThread[Table[#1, {#2}] &, {lis, Last /@ tal}]
```

> {12, 12, 12, 14, 14, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17}

Or

```
Flatten[ConstantArray @@@ Transpose[{lis, Last /@ tal}]]
```

Answer (score 5):

The following can be used also for unsorted lists:

```
SeedRandom[42];
l = RandomInteger[{3, 8}, 10]
l /. Thread[# -> expensive/@ #] &@Union@l

(* {6, 6, 5, 3, 7, 3, 7, 3, 7, 4} *)
(* {expensive[6], expensive[6], expensive[5], expensive[3], expensive[7],
    expensive[3], expensive[7], expensive[3], expensive[7], expensive[4]} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Given your initial list:

```
mylist = {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5};
```

another way to translate your approach is for example:

```
q[x_] := (Print["Computing..."]; f[x]);

Join @@ KeyValueMap[ConstantArray, KeyMap[q, Counts[mylist]]]
```

> ```
> Computing...
> Computing...
> Computing...
> Computing...
> Computing...
> {f[1],f[1],f[1],f[2],f[2],f[3],f[3],f[4],f[4],f[4],f[4],f[4],f[4],f[5]}
> ```

unless you prefer use the excellent memoization approach proposed by @Simon Woods:

```
p[x_] := p[x] = (Print["Computing..."];f[x]);
p /@ mylist
```

> ```
> Computing...
> Computing...
> Computing...
> Computing...
> Computing...
> {f[1],f[1],f[1],f[2],f[2],f[3],f[3],f[4],f[4],f[4],f[4],f[4],f[4],f[5]}
> ```

In both cases, you can see that computation of `f` took place only 5 times and not as many times as the number of elements in the list.

Answer (score 1):

```
tal = {{1, 3}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}, {4, 5}, {5, 1}};
lis = {12, 14, 15, 16, 17};
MapThread[Sequence @@ ConstantArray[#1, #2[[2]]] &, {lis, tal}]
```