# Opposite of Counts

Tags: list-manipulation, associations, counting

I would like to reverse the effect of `Counts`, i.e., starting with

```
x = <|a -> 4, b -> 2, c -> 1|>
```

I would like to reconstruct a sorted list

```
y = {a, a, a, a, b, b, c}
```

such that `Counts[y] == x`. I have come up with

```
y = Join @@ ConstantArray @@@ Normal @ x
```

but I'd like to know if there's anything more elegant than this, with less intermediary expressions.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate on Stack Overflow: [(763915)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/763915/618728)

Comment: Wow, I would never find that question in search for relateds, @Mr.Wizard. But what I take from your answer there is that the method I'm suggesting is about as good as it gets, right?

Comment: Well, it's what I would use, still; you can take that for what it's worth. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Catenate @ KeyValueMap[ConstantArray] @ x
```

Related topics:

[Reverse DeleteDuplicates using Information from Tally](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/98804/5478)

[Generating repeated elements in a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92728/5478)

[Replicate sublist in new list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/111863/5478)

[List creation/manipulation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56839/5478)

Comment: `Catenate @ KeyValueMap[Table] @ x` ought to work as well.

Comment: @J.M. yep, I think ConstantArray has better performance but I don't remember where to find benchmarks, I just use it by default. p.s. any idea why only the first link is automatically formatted?

Comment: I changed your links to use `https://`.

Comment: @J.M. thanks, I copied them from a comment made before recent se updates so that is probably it.

Comment: @Kuba A [little](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Mt3sd.png) and I think we even can ignored it.

Comment: @Kuba I believe the key difference is that if it is numeric input, `ConstantArray` generates packed arrays. But, `Catenate` doesn't respect packed arrays, so you instead have to use `Join @@ KeyValueMap[ConstantArray]@<|1 -> 4, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 1|>`, instead.

Comment: @yode `ConstantArray` and `Table` are not the same operation, even though `Table` may be fast enough due to autocompiliation.  As the name implies `ConstantArray` repeats a constant element, whereas `Table` presumes re-evaluation.

Answer (score 2):

```
KeyValueMap[Table /* Apply[Sequence], x]
```

> `{a, a, a, a, b, b, c}`

Answer (score 1):

Multiplication of Matrices

In:

```
xs = <|a -> 4, b -> 2, c -> 1|>;
A = Table[1, #] & /@ Values[xs]
B = Keys[xs]
A B // Flatten
```

Out:

```
{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1}}
{a, b, c}
{a, a, a, a, b, b, c}
```